# Explode with "NO_EMPTY" option, help to get a faster function

Tags: php

Basically I have this string

```
$str="word1    word2   word3";
```

I need

```
array(
  'word1',
  'word2',
  'word3'
);
```

I made this function:

```
function explodeStrict($delimiter,$string) {
    return preg_split("/{$delimiter}/",$string,null,PREG_SPLIT_NO_EMPTY);
}
```

But I need it to be fast. And this function is 2x slower than a simple `explode();` (within a 1mil loop)
 I have tried a vanilla style parsing each chars but it gets 7x slower than the `explode();`

Can you imagine a function as fast as explode that ignores empty elements?

With my function a 1milion loop takes 3.9 sec. 
Explode take 2 sec

Thanks

Comment: If speed is your main concern here, why are you using PHP?

Comment: Would it not be quicker to perform a simple explode, and then array_filter it? (Worth a test benchmarking it I'd have thought)

Comment: How often do you get 1M elements to parse in 2 seconds? The bottleneck must be somewhere else.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = 'word1    word2   word3';
$str = strtok($str, ' ');

$x = array();
while ($str !== false)
{
  $x[] = $str;
  $str = strtok(' ');
}
```

Comment: @yes123 right, changed my answer, on my computer, faster than `array_filter` solution.

Comment: this is awesome, almost as fast as explode.

Comment: funny thing is that this code is almost equal to example of strtok doc page

Comment: and the funnier thing is that you first provided the slowest answer and then the best. Congrats! :)

Comment: Haha, when I saw 3 comments notification, I thought it was flame :) I think it's faster because `strtok` is C function. Thanks.

Comment: @yes123 What was the speed of this one out of curiosity?

Answer (score 2):

Given:

```
$str="word1    word2   word3";
```

Try:

```
return array_filter(explode(" ",$str));
```

Comment: Quite sure it's the fastest approach.

Answer (score 1):

```
function explodeStrict($delimiter,$string) {
    return preg_split("/" . preg_quote($delimiter, "/") . "+/", $string);
}
```

Comment: That's a bit faster. a 1mil loop now takes 3.5 sec vs 3.9